# lambda calculus evaluation

Tags: lambda

I'm new here and new to lambda calculus. My question is:
In lambda calculus reduction (to normal form), is there a way to evaluate the expression (to make sure I did the reduction correctly).

for example (/ stands for lambda)
(using beta method)

`/x.y(/z.xz))(/y.zy)`

`=> /x.y(/z.xz))z`
`=> (/x.yx)z`
`=> yz`

now how to make sure my reduction is right? is there a way i can evaluate the original one and compare it to the reduced one?

Comment: Have you checked at http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I agree with @MortenJensen - this isn't a programming-related question so it shouldn't be on SO.

Comment: There is an unmatched right parenthesis in `/x.y(/z.xz))(/y.zy)`.

Comment: Also the first `y` and the last `z` appear to be free, or they are being used outside their context of definition.

Answer (score 1):

What you did there already was the evaluation of that Lambda expression. If you mean *let a computer evaluate it*, a lambda function like this one

[image: formula]

is written like this in Haskell:

```
(\a b => b a)
```

Python:

```
lambda a, b: b(a)
```

C#:

```
(a, b) => b(a)
```